# Is there a way to programmatically get a list of the different departments Enterprise Fields belong to?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2013, ms-project-server-2010, ms-project-server-2016

As far as I know, Enterprise Fields can be setup in Project Server to belong to a particular *Department*. I believe this would make it so a certain profiles would have access to certain Enterprise fields only if they are part of the same department (hoping whoever answers this question can confirm my assumption or not).

My question is, is it possible to programmatically get a list of all of the different departments that are associated with the Enterprise Fields without actually having access to the project server?

Looking at the Project Information window makes me think it may be possible

[image]